# PHP Website Statistics

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

i have put this PHP code at the very top of my index.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbconnection.php';

$sql="INSERT into site_statistics (ipaddress, datetime, url) values ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."') ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

It inserts into the database ok but it seems to always put multiple rows in the table when i just refresh the once

The session_start(); is used for my shopping cart so i cannot remove this

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: His question is logically "Why am I having multiple rows inserted with just one hit to my page?"

Comment: there could be several reasons - do you execute other queries later and still use the same value/variable `$sql`? is there a redirect happening that causes your index page to be loaded multiple times?

Comment: there is other $sql down the page but i have just tried changing this to $stats_sql and $rs_sql.
There is nothing else at all that uses these variables but still the same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

add in a column that is a varchar(32), make it the primary key, and insert the session id into it. ie.

```
$sql="INSERT into site_statistics (sid, ipaddress, datetime, url) values ('" . session_id() . "', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."') ";
```

the session id is unique to the visitor at that particular time, so it being the primary key would prevent multiple inserts of the same visitor on that particular visit.

Comment: just tried this but still the same issue. it keeps putting 5 rows in each time i refresh the page once

Comment: have you set the sid column as the primary key? you cant have duplicate primary keys, and the session id is the same for that visit as long as you dont close the browser or as long as you regenerate the sid in the code manually.

Comment: what i want eventually is to log every page that one person visits. so they go onto the website and it logs that have looked at the first page, then they go onto page2.php so it logs this too etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the field when page refresh, use

```
REPLACE INTO
```

in your sql query, but if not, you can check the database first using

```
if(...){
  ...
}
```

statement.